# error "expression must have a constant value"

Tags: c

When I am using const variables "a" & "b" to init a structed variable "cfg" I am facing the following compiler issue "expression must have a constant value"

```
static const unsigned int a = 1;
static const unsigned int b = 2;


typedef struct
{
    const uint32 InitTypestruct_elem1;   
    const uint32 InitTypestruct_elem2;   
}InitType;

typedef struct
{
    InitType BoardTypestruct_elem1;
}BoardType;


static const BoardType cfg =
{
    /* pbgc cfg */
    .BoardTypestruct_elem1 =
    {
        ***.InitTypestruct_elem1 = a,
        ***.InitTypestruct_elem2 = b
    }
};


const InitType *cfg(void)
{
    return &cfg.BoardTypestruct_elem1;
}


int main()
{
    //cfg

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler warning causes in the line with ***

why this issue is happening? a and b are const values?

Comment: Is this a warning or an error? Does the program compile?

Comment: Because `const` defines a "read-only" object, not a constant "typed" value. Try `enum /*untagged*/ { a = 1, b };` and let the compiler make its type guesses and conversions.

Comment: @pmg: yes with a enum this issue is not pops up again but then i get another compiler warning e.g.

static const unsigned int a = 0x80000000;

compiler says: a is out of range of type int. The compiler uses int for enum variables

Comment: Your other option is using `#define A 0x80000000U`

Comment: A `const` variable (more or less) is one that won't be changed by the program after initialisation.   It doesn't turn a variable into a compile-time constant.   If you want a compile-time constant, use a literal value (like `1` or `2`).   If you want to give it a name, of sorts, use a macro that expands to a literal or an expression involving literals  e.g. `#define a 1` or `#define b (a + 1)`.    There are gotchas with preprocessor macros though, so do some homework to understand the pitfalls BEFORE using them.   You can also use enums, such as `enum {a = 1, b = 2};`

Comment: OT:  when defining structs, always include a 'tag' name.  This is because most debuggers use the 'tag' name to be able to display the individual fields within the struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a variable of *static storage duration* with anything but a *constant expression*, an integer constant expression in this case.

Unfortunately, C makes a difference between integer constant expressions and "`const` qualified" variables. (C and C++ are different here.) This means that the initializer of your `cfg` variable must be an integer constant (for example `1`), an enum or a `#define` value, or an expression formed by such operands.

That is, if you do any arithmetic inside the initializer, all operands must be integer constants.
So `1 + 1` would be fine, but not `a + 1`, if `a` is a variable.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying the other answers:

```
static const unsigned int a = 1;
```

`a` is a variable, no matter that it is const. You cannot initialize a global variable with another (global) variable at compile-time. The compiler does not see it as constant.

Comment: when i am placing the variable declaration of a and b into the fct const InitType *cfg(void) then it is working! But then i have the issue that I am returning a stack address! this is not allowed. Is it possible to move the cfg variable into read only area by using compiler directives?

Comment: The `cfg` function performs the initialization (assignment) in _run-time_. That is not a problem. You can have a global variable and peform the initialization (assignment) in the function, and that is no problem either because then it is done in run-time too. The point is that _compile-time_ initialization must be a constant expression.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
> literals.

and (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 2 A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather
> than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant
> may be.

and

> 7 More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers.
> Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the
> following:
>
> — an arithmetic constant expression,
>
> — a null pointer constant,
>
> — an address constant, or
>
> — an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an
> integer constant expression

and

> 8 An arithmetic constant expression shall have arithmetic type and
> shall only have operands that are integer constants, floating
> constants, enumeration constants, character constants, and sizeof
> expressions. Cast operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall
> only convert arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of
> an operand to a sizeof operator whose result is an integer constant.

You could use enumerators instead of these declarations

```
static const unsigned int a = 1;
static const unsigned int b = 2;
```

For example

```
enum { A = 1, B = 2 };

static const BoardType cfg = {
    /* pbgc cfg */
    .BoardTypestruct_elem1 =
    {
        .InitTypestruct_elem1 = A,
        .InitTypestruct_elem2 = B
    } };
```